# How to parse a stringified JSON field and render results with react-admin

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, react-admin

I'm using react-admin with Amplify. One of my graphql types has an AWSJSON field containing an array of statuses for a batchJob. I'd like this array to be shown in a datagrid that the user can expand to see result of each item in the batch.

The data is returned from the API as stringified JSON. How can I JSON.parse the data then pass it to ArrayField to be rendered by Datagrid in my list/show components?

The contents of the field look like this:

```
[{"reference":"11134","status":"OK"},{"reference":"10278","status":"OK"}]
```

UPDATE: the answer below was after I updated the data model a bit to:

```
[{"id": "somerandomuid", "clientReference":"11134","status":"OK"}]
```

My code looks like this:

Schema:

```
  type JobTask
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner }
      { allow: groups, groups: ["admins"] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  results: AWSJSON
  status: String
  expiryDate: AWSTimestamp! @ttl
}
```

Show Component:

```
  export const TaskShow = (props) => {
    return (
    <Show title={props.header} {...props}>
      <SimpleShowLayout>
        <Datagrid expand={<ResultsPanel />}>
          <TextField
            key={cuid()}
            fullWidth={true}
            source="id"
            label="Batch Id"
          />
          <TextField
            key={cuid()}
            fullWidth={true}
            source="status"
            label="Status"
          />
        </Datagrid>
      </SimpleShowLayout>
    </Show>
    );
```

ResultsPanel Component:

```
const ResultsPanel = (props) => {
  console.log(props)
  let resultsArray = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(props.record.results));
  console.log(resultsArray);
  return (
    <>
      {resultsArray.map((result) => {
        return (
          <ArrayField>
            <Datagrid>
              <TextField source="reference" />
              <TextField source="status" />
            </Datagrid>
          </ArrayField>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

But all I get is:

[image: Screenshot of react-admin component]

Comment: Why are you parsing twice here `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(props.record.results))`?

Comment: That's a Very Good Question. For some reason, the string is double stringified. If I only parse it once, the type is still a string and map fails.

Comment: That's interesting. Is the string value `'[{"reference":"11134","status":"OK"},{"reference":"10278","status":"OK"}]'`? If parse that, I get an array of objects on my side. Also, could you share the `TextField` component? Not sure if it's part of a library or not, but I'm afraid you're indeed only displaying the field name, not the value.

Comment: that's a console log of the values. But that's not really the problem. The problem is how do I get that parsed value 'into' react admin datagrid component?

Comment: Oh yeah. I'm not familiar with `react-admin`, but all the examples that use `Datagrid` in the documentation have `Datagrid` wrapped by `List`. Also, it seems that when you use `ArrayField`, you need to determine a `source`, which is the name of the object attribute and I see you're not doing that. More here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#arrayfield

Comment: Yea - I tried passing source={data} to ArrayField, no joy. I suspect source will always refer to the original "stringified" value, not the parsed one I've generated from it. I'm now looking into <ListContentProvider> but it's not documented, as far as I can tell. That looks to be able to pass a set of records down into a datagrid.

Comment: Right, right, but `source`, according to the documentation, should be a string, not an object or array.

Comment: First off, you don't need to map through results if you're using `ArrayField`. Apparently, that `react-admin` component already does that for you. Have you tried saying `source` is equal to `results`?

Comment: Yea - worked that out last night. The problem with the source prop is you'\re right, it's a string. I assume it's used as a parameter of a function inside the component. After a lot of messing around with the list contextprovider, I've concluded that won't work either. Suspect that's because it needs to live in a list component, not a show one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd post my findings for anyone else who might be struggling with this.

Datagrid requires a context, which a list component will provide for it, but as this is in a show component, I was trying to use Array instead to provide the context.

ArrayField component requires a source prop that must be a string that maps exactly to a field/property in the API response; it *can't* be an arbitrary object/array. The property the string maps to however must be an array, and there's no way to tell the component to process the contents of that field/property before using it. So Arrayfield is out as a context provider.

As Array doesn't work with my data structure, I thought I could use RA's listcontextprovider, which isn't very well documented, but does seem to allow you to build a context that can be used by datagrid, as far as I can tell. But it always gave me an error when I used it with the correct props (as far as I could tell, anyway - as I say, the documentation is a bit sparse).

In the end, I abandoned native RA components as a bad fit for my use-case and went with writing a custom field component that does what I need instead (i.e. parse the field from the record and pass the array to a datagrid to render). I used native MUI datagrid, which works like a charm:

```
const ResultsPanel = (props) => {
  let resultsArray = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(props.record.results));
  let columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "Item Id", flex: 1 },
    { field: "clientReference", headerName: "Your Reference", flex: 1 },
    { field: "status", headerName: "Import Status", flex: 1 },
  ];
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid columns={columns} rows={resultsArray} />
    </div>
  );
};
```